# How to skip attribute error on regex function

Tags: python

Is there a way to check if the regular expression result is `None`, and then skip the record? I get attribute errors on `end` and `start`.

This isn't my code, but I believe the function looks for `)`. But if a cell doesn't have a `)`, I believe it is causing attribute errors.

```
def extract_Access_Rule(text):
            if re.search('DATA[(]',text):
                return text[re.search('[)]', text).end()+1 : re.search('DATA[(]', text).start()]
            else:
                return text[re.search('[)]', text).end()+1:]

access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule_Value'] = access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule'].apply(lambda text : extract_Access_Rule(text))
access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule_Value'] =access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule_Value'].apply(lambda text : text.replace(".",""))
database_regex = 'UID[(]'
access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule_DataBase'] = access_HR_attestaion_application['Access_Rule'].apply(lambda text: text[:re.search(database_regex,text).start()] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you just need to add "is not None" to the end of your if statement to ensure it only completes if it finds what it's looking for.

```
if re.search('DATA[(]',text) is not None:
```

Comment: sorry @funkb did not work..